# Content filtering on macOS

Tags: ios, macos, provisioning-profile, entitlements, networkextension

Is [NEFilterManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefiltermanager?language=objc) supported for macOS 10.13 also or only iOS? On macOS, import and `[NEFilterManager sharedManager]` are working but in the project's `capability` why is `content filter` field not available for macOS apps? Is it some configuration that is missing?

[image]